# Multiple objects fail to render?

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

My should display two squares on the screen but when I run it all I see is a screen of nothingness.

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>




struct Shaderprogramsource
{
std::string VertexSouce;
std::string FragmentSource;
};

static Shaderprogramsource Parseshader(const std::string& filepath)
{
std::ifstream stream(filepath);

enum class Shadertype
{
    VERTEX = 0,
    FRAGMENT = 1,
    NONE = 5
};

std::string line;
std::stringstream ss[3];

Shadertype type = Shadertype::NONE;

while (getline(stream, line))
{
    if (line.find("#shader") != std::string::npos)
    {
        if (line.find("vertex") != std::string::npos)
            type = Shadertype::VERTEX;

        else if (line.find("fragment") != std::string::npos)
            type = Shadertype::FRAGMENT;
    }
    else
    {
        ss[(int)type] << line << "\n";
    }
}

return Shaderprogramsource{ ss[0].str(), ss[1].str() };
}

static int CompileShader(unsigned int type, const std::string& Source)
{
unsigned int id = glCreateShader(type);
const char* src = Source.c_str();
glShaderSource(id, 1, &src, nullptr);
glCompileShader(id);

int result;
glGetShaderiv(id, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &result);

if (result == GL_FALSE)
{
    int length;
    glGetShaderiv(id, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &length);

    char* message = (char*)alloca(length * sizeof(char));
    glGetShaderInfoLog(id, length, &length, message);

    std::cout << message;

    return 0;
}

return id;
}

static unsigned int CreateShader(
const std::string& Vertexshader,
const std::string& Fragmentshader)
{
unsigned int program = glCreateProgram();
unsigned int vertex = CompileShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, Vertexshader);
unsigned int fragment = CompileShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, Fragmentshader);

glAttachShader(program, vertex);
glAttachShader(program, fragment);

glLinkProgram(program);
glValidateProgram(program);

return program;
}

int main(void)
{
GLFWwindow* window;

/* Initialize the library */
if (!glfwInit())
    return -1;

glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);






/* Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context */
window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 800, "Hello World", NULL, NULL);
if (!window)
{
    glfwTerminate();
    return -1;
}

/* Make the window's context current */
glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

if (GLEW_OK == glewInit())
{
}

float vertices[] = { -0.1, -0.1,
                      0.1, -0.1, 
                      0.1, 0.1, 
                     -0.1, 0.1 };



float vertices2[] = { -0.1,0.1,
                      0.1, 0.1,
                      0.1, 0.3,
                     -0.1, 0.3 };


unsigned int indices[] = {

    0, 1, 2,
    2, 3, 0


};

unsigned int vao;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
glBindVertexArray(vao);

unsigned int vao2;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao2);
glBindVertexArray(vao2);


unsigned int buffer1;

unsigned int vbo;

glGenBuffers(1, &buffer1);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer1);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 4 * 2 * sizeof(float), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 2, 0);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 2, 0);



glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 6 * sizeof(unsigned int), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);





Shaderprogramsource source = Parseshader("res/shaders/Basic.Shader");

unsigned int shader =
    CreateShader(source.VertexSouce, source.FragmentSource);




glUseProgram(shader);


int location = glGetUniformLocation(shader, "Color_u");
if (location > -1) {
    glUniform4f(location, 0.8f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

}



std::cout << source.VertexSouce;

glUseProgram(0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

/* Loop until the user closes the window */
while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
{
    /* Render here */

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glUseProgram(shader);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vao);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vao2);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);


    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 2, 0);

    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 2, 0);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

    glUseProgram(shader);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, nullptr);

    /* Swap front and back buffers */
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);

    /* Poll for and process events */
    glfwPollEvents();
}

glDeleteProgram(shader);

glfwTerminate();
return 0;
}
```

Shaders:

```
#shader vertex
#version 330 core

layout(location = 0) in vec3 position;



void main()
{
gl_Position = vec4(position.x, position.y, position.z, 1.0);
};

#shader fragment
#version 330 core

layout(location = 0) out vec4 color;

uniform vec4 Color_u;

void main()
{
color = Color_u;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All sorts of wonk-a-donk:

- `Parseshader()` is broken if the first line starts with anything other than the magic `#shader` directive, since `NONE` is set to 5 and the `ss[(int)type]` index + assignment will walk right off the end of the 3-element `ss` array.  Drop `NONE` down to `2`.
- You only have a single vertex attribute in your shader (`0`) yet you're trying to set up `1`.
- That's not how VAOs work *at all*.  A VAO has *never* been a valid argument to `glBindBuffer()`.  Intead, bind a VAO & then set up your vertex attribute bindings/layouts:

  ```
  unsigned int vao1 = 0;
  glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao1);
  glBindVertexArray(vao1);
  glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ebo);
  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer1);
  glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 2, 0);
  glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
  ```

  Then later when you want to draw you can re-bind the VAO and immediately draw, skipping all the `glBindBuffer()`/`glVertexAttribPointer()`/`glEnableVertexAttribArray()` setup.

All together:

[image: screenshot]

```cpp
// g++ -g main.cpp `pkg-config --cflags --libs glfw3 glew`
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

const char* const shaderSource = R"GLSL(
#shader vertex
#version 330 core
layout(location = 0) in vec3 position;
void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(position.x, position.y, position.z, 1.0);
};

#shader fragment
#version 330 core
layout(location = 0) out vec4 color;
uniform vec4 Color_u;
void main()
{
    color = Color_u;
};
)GLSL";

struct Shaderprogramsource
{
    std::string VertexSouce;
    std::string FragmentSource;
};

static Shaderprogramsource Parseshader(const std::string& shaderString)
{
    std::stringstream stream( shaderString );

    enum class Shadertype
    {
        VERTEX = 0,
        FRAGMENT = 1,
        NONE = 2
    };

    std::string line;
    std::stringstream ss[3];

    Shadertype type = Shadertype::NONE;

    while( std::getline(stream, line) )
    {
        if (line.find("#shader") != std::string::npos)
        {
            if (line.find("vertex") != std::string::npos)
                type = Shadertype::VERTEX;

            else if (line.find("fragment") != std::string::npos)
                type = Shadertype::FRAGMENT;
        }
        else
        {
            ss[(int)type] << line << '\n';
        }
    }

    return Shaderprogramsource{ ss[0].str(), ss[1].str() };
    }

static int CompileShader(unsigned int type, const std::string& Source)
{
    unsigned int id = glCreateShader(type);
    const char* src = Source.c_str();
    glShaderSource(id, 1, &src, nullptr);
    glCompileShader(id);

    int result;
    glGetShaderiv(id, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &result);

    if (result == GL_FALSE)
    {
        int length;
        glGetShaderiv(id, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &length);

        char* message = (char*)alloca(length * sizeof(char));
        glGetShaderInfoLog(id, length, &length, message);

        std::cout << message;

        return 0;
    }

    return id;
}

static unsigned int CreateShader( const std::string& Vertexshader, const std::string& Fragmentshader )
{
    unsigned int program = glCreateProgram();
    unsigned int vertex = CompileShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, Vertexshader);
    unsigned int fragment = CompileShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, Fragmentshader);

    glAttachShader(program, vertex);
    glAttachShader(program, fragment);

    glLinkProgram(program);
    glValidateProgram(program);

    return program;
}

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    if (!glfwInit())
        return -1;

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Hello World", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    /* Make the window's context current */
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    if (GLEW_OK == glewInit())
    {
    }

    unsigned int buffer1;
    glGenBuffers(1, &buffer1);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer1);
    float vertices1[] =
    {
        -0.1, -0.1,
        0.1, -0.1, 
        0.1, 0.1, 
        -0.1, 0.1,
    };
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices1), vertices1, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    unsigned int buffer2;
    glGenBuffers(1, &buffer2);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer2);
    float vertices2[] =
    {
        -0.1, 0.1,
        0.1, 0.1,
        0.1, 0.3,
        -0.1, 0.3,
    };
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices2), vertices2, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    unsigned int ebo;
    glGenBuffers(1, &ebo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ebo);
    unsigned int indices[] =
    {
        0, 1, 2,
        2, 3, 0,
    };
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    unsigned int vao1 = 0;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao1);
    glBindVertexArray(vao1);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ebo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer1);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 2, 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    unsigned int vao2 = 0;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao2);
    glBindVertexArray(vao2);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ebo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer2);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 2, 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    Shaderprogramsource source = Parseshader( shaderSource );
    unsigned int shader = CreateShader(source.VertexSouce, source.FragmentSource);
    glUseProgram(shader);
    int location = glGetUniformLocation(shader, "Color_u");

    /* Loop until the user closes the window */
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        glfwPollEvents();

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glUseProgram(shader);

        if (location > -1)
        {
            glUniform4f(location, 0.8f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        }
        glBindVertexArray(vao1);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, nullptr);

        if (location > -1)
        {
            glUniform4f(location, 0.0f, 0.8f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        }
        glBindVertexArray(vao2);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, nullptr);

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    }

    glDeleteProgram(shader);

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you have to rebind everything with the VAO's? Just curious.

Comment: @Jerryoff:  What do you mean by "rebind everything"?  Are you talking about the re-binding of buffer1/buffer2/ebo during the VAO setup?

Comment: yah the buffers.

Comment: @Jerryoff: You have to rebind since the `glBindVertexArray()` call resets the binding points to whatever is in the VAO.  Since the VAOs haven't been bound before those binding points will default to zero, which either means pull from client memory (Compatibility contexts) or invalid buffer object (Core contexts).